# Linking R Environment into Visual Studio Code

Tags: r

I'm able to connect fine on on R studio, but when I try to use R in VS Code, I am unable to attach the R environment. I'm guessing it is a path issue and I have tracked down R.4.2.2 exe to my downloads folder.

When attempting to connect R to Visual Studio Code I received an error stating the terminal process failed to launch. Cannot Find R client.

I have tried changing the file path multiple times to different exe locations of R but the error message still occurs.

I still am unable to connect Visual Studio Code to an R environment.

Cannot find R client at C:\Users\kmussar\AppData\Local\Programs\R\R-4.2.2\bin\x64\Rgui.exe --cd-to-userdocs. Please check r.rterm setting.